# Maven resources plugin does not filter resources on Grails project

Tags: maven, grails, resources

I have a Grails project that builds with Maven.
There in this project is a resource file `smth.properties` and the last line there looks like:

```
build.number=${build.number}
```

I tried to use `maven-resources-plugin` to filter it and fill when `mvn -Dbuild.number=1.0 install` is executed, but seems that plugin does not work because `grails-maven-plugin` does.
The same code but without Grails works perfectly.

How can I filter resources with Grails to fill all the fields `${name}` with `-Dname=value` on `mvn install`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of configuring the `maven-resources-plugin` you can add resources filtering directly inside the `<build/>` tag:

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
        <name>my default value</name>
    </properties>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Then run using your command line:

```
mvn -Dname=myNewValue install
```

Comment: Nothing happens. `${build.number}` still in WAR-file

Answer (score 0):

Maven resources processing is basically a copy of your resources, from one directory to another, replacing placeholders.

It's bound to the  process-resources life-cycle phase.

If you want to reprocess the resources with another plugin, a simple way is to configure them to 
1 ) first plugin, take resources from folderA and copy to folder B (with some processing)
2 ) second plugin, take resources from folderB, and copy to folderC

And to bind to 2 differents phases, to ensure a correct order of execution.

> resources:resources copies the resources for the main source code to
>   the main output directory.
>
> This goal usually executes automatically, because it is bound by
>   default to the process-resources life-cycle phase. It always uses the
>   project.build.resources element to specify the resources, and by
>   default uses the project.build.outputDirectory to specify the copy
>   destination.

Comment: `mvn resources:resources` works great. `mvn install` starts `grails-war-plugin` and filtering doesn't work.

Comment: Sure, but both try to work on the same source file, and one might overwrite the file computed by the other. That's why you should care about what the plugins are doing, and make sure one works on the RESULT of the other